# WIFI card Settings Missing 802.11N?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, internet, wifi-configuration

The picture says it all..
I have the latest intel driver installed

this is a wireless-n 7260 from intel.. any idea?..

[image]

Comment: Do you have a 802.11n enabled router?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes the router already has `performance mode (N - only) enabled` not sure if that means my pc is already running on N

Comment: What is the router wireless encryption mode setting? What is the wireless HT mode setting?

Comment: it is using wpa2 or whatever that one that supports this mode. I can only assume that this function is working, but no real way of telling that it is.. since there is no N mode in my setting for some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source Wireless Networking
[What are the recommended settings for 802.11n connectivity?](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/sb/CS-030709.htm)

> These are the default settings for Intel® wireless adapters supporting
>   802.11n. These recommended settings can be found under the Advanced menu on Intel® PROSet/Wireless Software. Learn how to access and
>   configure advanced Wi-Fi adapter settings.
>
> [image]
>
> On the wireless router check the following options:
>
> [image]
>
> Note
>
> **WEP and WPA-TKIP are not compatible with 802.11n.**

Comment: actually my screenshot seems to already be at this location.. its just that the setting isn't there.. the so-called `802.11n mode`